# Javascript HTML play sound only once, but more strange thing happened

Tags: javascript, audio, codepen

I tried this simple snippet in codepen. and function once1 can play as many times as you want while once2 can play sound only once.
Anyone know what's the difference?

```
var  simple = new 
Audio("http://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3" );
var birdSound = new 
Audio('http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/4929.mp3');

birdSound.loop = false;
simple.loop = false;
function once1(){
  birdSound.play(); 
};
function once2(){
  simple.play(); 
};
```

Comment: can you share your codepen link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, I saw the other answer still wasn't working on jsfiddle or codepen so try this!

```
var  simple = new 
Audio("http://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3" );
var birdSound = new 
Audio('http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/4929.mp3');

birdSound.loop = false;
simple.loop = false;
function once1(){
    birdSound.load();
  birdSound.play(); 
};
function once2(){
    simple.load();
  simple.play(); 
};
```

Just use `.load` :D

Answer (score 0):

Update: Using the `load()` method, as suggested by the other poster, I can get the code below to repeatedly play the second sound in Chrome, but it still sounds different than it does in Firefox. In Firefox the sound plays smoothly, but in Chrome the sound ends more abruptly, with a little bit of a crackle or click. I suspect that there's just something about this particular sound file that isn't fully compatible with Chrome.

---

I'm able to get both sounds to play as many times as I want in Firefox with this Plunker here, but not in Chrome: http://plnkr.co/edit/gM8lobVoQoAtVSlwVZNC?p=preview

```js
function init() {
  var simple = new Audio("http://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3" );
  var birdSound = new Audio('http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/4929.mp3');

  birdSound.loop = false;
  simple.loop = false;

  function once1() {
    birdSound.play(); 
  }

  function once2() {
    simple.load();
    simple.play(); 
  }

  var btn1 = document.getElementById("one");
  btn1.addEventListener('click', once1);

  var btn2 = document.getElementById("two");
  btn2.addEventListener('click', once2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body onload="init()">
    <button id="one">Sound 1</button><br>
    <button id="two">Sound 2</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Which web browser were you using?